# What variables can be affected by function call

Tags: javascript

How to get list of variables which will be potentially affected by function?

Let's imagine I have a next constructor:

```
  var myInstance = new function(){
     var that = this;
     that.a = 5;
     that.b = {t:33:g:"fff"};
     that.c = "param";
     that.myCoolFunc = function(){
         that.a = 100;
         if(something){
            b.t = 1;
         }
         // Whatever some other operations
     }
  }
```

Is there any generic way to understand before calling `myInstance.myCoolFunc()` to get the list of variables that function will potentially affect(change)?

Example usage:

```
getListOfAffectedVariables(myInstance.myCoolFunc); // will return - ["a", "b.t",...]
```

Comment: Well immediately this comes to mind: have an array in your function constructor with all the keys when you build it next what happens if you console.log(myInstance)

Comment: You would need to analyze the program in the same way a parser does, but even that would not allow you to deterministically find what properties (not variables) would be affected. You could make a proxy of the object to catch property accesses, then call the function and find which properties were set. By the way, I assume you mean `that.b.t`. And that you mean `new myInstance().myCoolFunc()`. Also, why are you using `that` at all?

Comment: Yes, I miss-typed I mean `that.b.t` instead of just `b.t`. No, i didn't mean `new myInstance().myCoolFunc()` cause myInstance already is an instance of constructor. As you might know var that = this;(or someone uses `self`) prevents a unknown behavior of `this`.

Comment: As far as I know javascript interpreter does something similar with functions which have access to the outer variables. I just trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I know.

There is no metadata for the body of a function regarding such information.